# How to connect a local virtual machine to a remote server via SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, vmware

I usually connect to the remote server with [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net) and a VPN, but now I need to connect a VM in my local machine to the remote server, I have access to the internet in the VM, the network adapter on the VM is on bridged, I open a terminal and try to connect to the remote server using this command:

```
ssh myuser@myip -p myport
```

But always get:

> “Connection timed out…”

Is there something more that I have to do to get the VM work with the VPN?

Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your guest VM is not connected to the host connected VPN if you are in bridged networking. You must use NAT networking instead.

> “I usually connect to the remote server with MobaXterm and a VPN…”

That’s the problem. If you need to connect to a machine via a VPN and can do it from your host OS but cannot do it from your guest OS it’s because bridged mode circumvents whatever VPN connection you have on your host OS.

The three modes I am aware of are as follows:

- **Bridged networking**: Unique IP address on the network independent of the host OS.
- **Host-only networking**: A network localized to the host OS.
- **Network Address Translation (NAT) networking**: A network connection that is associated to your host OS’s internet connection.

Knowing that, you should set your guest OS to Network Address Translation (NAT) networking and restart the VM. Once that is done, you should be able to SSH as expected since the VM will now being using the network connection on the host OS that includes the VPN related networking.